# Is Allah [swt] the creator of both good and evil?

Tags: quran, theology

I was studying Surah Al-Falaq and I noticed that in the second verse, according to the translation of Sahih International, it is written: "From the evil of that which He created". Is Allah [swt] the creator of evil or I've misunderstood? Please clear my doubt, thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the verse again. It specifically states "the evil of that which He created."

This essentially means that the evil comes from the creation and not from Allah. Think of it this way, using an analogy: A car manufacturer manufactures cars, *not* accidents; which means that a car manufacturer does his utmost to produce a safe and sound car. Unfortunately, a driver may mishandle the car which may result in an accident. The car manufacturer is hardly to blame for it, since he designed the best and safest car, and also gave the driver detailed instructions on how to drive it. If the driver failed to abide by the manufacturer's instructions, then the latter is not responsible for the accident.

Similarly, Allah created His creation and gave them the ability to do both right and wrong, along with a moral understanding of the consequences, as well as the results of their transgressions. This is a test for *all* humans, regardless of place or time.

Allah also sent Messengers (PBUT) from time to time to instruct humans and correct their course from deviations from the True Path that may have occurred over the course of time. The Messengers (PBUT) also instructed their flocks about the consequences of their deeds, good or bad. After this, it was left to each individual to believe and do deeds that please Allah, and abstain from deeds that displease Him. If they do evil, that evil is a consequence of their deeds, and Allah is not to be blamed for it.

HTH.

Comment: Another analogy: The professor creates the questions that cause students to fail the test. The professor is not to blame if the students fail, especially if many others were given more difficult tests.